Windows FTP Server connects on 21 but times out on port 22
We've set up a Windows IIS on Windows 10.  We can connect to the FTP server using Filezilla + WinSCP on the local network from port 21.  When we try to connect to port 22 using sFTP, the connection attemp times out.
We do have a binding setup for port 22.
We do have a security certificate from GoDaddy configured on the server. The server is configured to require SSL connections.
We can connect to the FTP server using command prompt on port 22.
We've disabled the firewall for testing. (host and client)
There is no third party anti-virus on the PC, just windows defender (temporarily disabled)
We've checked to make sure no other sevices are usign port 22. (there are none)
Test-NetConnection on port 22 from PowerShell reports TcpTestSucceeded = true.
netstat -an | findstr ":22" shows 0.0.0.0:22 LISTENING, When filezilla or WinSCP is open and either trying to connect or after a failed conenct, netstat shows 192.168.1.122:22 ESTABLISHED.

Note that port 22 is reserved for SSH and used by file transfer protocols like scp and or sftp which is completely different to what IIS provides and supports. As far as I know IIS only supports clear text FTP and the TLS secured version  FTPS  which sounds similar and often gets confused. FTP and FTPS usually require port 21 for the control session and a second port for data transfers.

It looks like you're confusing FTPS with SFTP. The former is a TLS-encapsulated traditional FTP and is supported with IIS, while the latter is file transfer protocol based on the SSH (secure shell) and it isn't supported by IIS.
Windows started supporting true SSH-based file transfers via SFTP protocol on the port 22 (by default, configurable) with the corresponding OpenSSH Server feature.
This is what you need to install if you intend to use SFTP, instead of binding IIS to that port.
